# Call addSeries() from within addSeries event

Tags: highcharts

I want to add a reference series to my charts (i.e. a reference price). [Axis.addPlotLine()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotLine) does it, but I want to be able to toggle this series from the legend; a plain plotLine does not show up in the graph's legend.

Another reason why plotLine does not seem like a good solution is that it does not get accounted for by the viewport calculations. Which means that toggling other series might lead to the plotLine appearing outside the viewport due to zooming.

The simplest way to accomplish what I want would be, to add a dynamic series via `chart.addSeries`. But it's impossible to call this method from within a triggered *addSeries event* because `chart.addSeries` is set to `null` while in the event handler.

Tying in to the *redraw event* creates a whole lot of difficulties as well, because `render()` can't be called anymore.

How would you go about it?

**Update:**

As per the comment of Pawel Fus, I unsuccessfully tried the following:

```
[…]
events: {
    load: function (event) {
      foo = this;
    },
    addSeries: function(event) {
      console.log(foo) // returns chart object as expected
      console.log(foo.addSeries) // undefined
    }
}
```

Comment: The `plotLine` is still your best bet if the value does not change.  `plotLine` spans the whole range of the chart across that value regardless of series added. You can add a button to toggle the `plotLine` on/off.

Comment: `addSeries` is disabled to prevent infinite loop. The same in `redraw` callback you can't use `chart.redraw()`

Comment: @PawełFus yeah, that's what I thought but that's unfortunate because I could easily prevent the infinite loop by checking whether the series is already there.

Comment: You can in `load` event store `addSeries` function, then use stored function in callback.

Comment: @PawełFus Could you elaborate on this, please? I tried storing the chart object during `load` (see the update in my question) but `addSeries()` is still undefined.

Comment: I mean something like that: `foo = this.addSeries;` Then use `foo(obj);`

Comment: Tried that as well and it results in the following error: `foo(obj); // TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'initSeries'`

Comment: See my answer - I hope that works for you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to store `addSeries` on load event, and use stored function when adding series. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/808/

```
        events: {
            load: function (event) {
                foo = this.addSeries;
            },
            addSeries: function (event) {
                if (iterator) {
                    iterator--;
                    foo.call(this, {
                        data: [100, 200, 100, 100, 200, 300]
                    });
                }

            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Still you can stick with plotLine only.
If the position of the line is static that is the best way.

If the position is dynamic then you can still go with plotLine.
There are events for adding and removing plotLine on the fly.

API link
removePLotLine() : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.removePlotLine
addPlotLine() : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotLine

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I agree that plotLine seems to be the best idea at first sight. But I don't want to introduce another interface (i.e. a button) to toggle the plotLine because that's already possible for all other series via the graph's legend.